# How can I optimize these null-checking operations?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I have a SQL Reader object over which I iterate, and as things usually go, you never quite know what you're going to get.  Whatever value is returned by the reader needs to be cast as a double, but if it returns a null I need to gracefully handle it with a default value, which in this case is zero. I started out with code similar to this...

```
double x;
if (reader[1] is double)
    x = (double)reader[1];
else
    x = 0;
```

... which seemed to do the trick, but I wasn't satisfied.  I figured that the mysterious team that designs C# would have an operator for this, and what do you know, [there is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx).  So, then I ended up with a slightly different implementation...

```
var x = reader[1] as Double? ?? 0;
```

I couldn't tell you if the two examples above are equivalent because like all newbs I take code that I think will do the trick and use it for important things - partial joke.  What I do know is that I have yet for either implementation to throw an exception when hitting the database and getting a null result, and this leads me to believe that *both work as I expect* but I'd rather be sure.

So, on to my questions.  Can someone explain what potential differences in functionality I could experience from using either?  If possible, could someone provide/explain a better implementation of the second example?  I find the null-coalesce operator pretty sexy but I don't really know if I'm implementing it in the best way.  Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could also write: `var x = (reader[1] as Double?).GetValueOrDefault();`. This has the benefit of `x` being a `double` and not `double?`. But this also hides incompatible values. What if `reader[1]` returned a `string` instead because you reordered the return values? Instead of getting an exception (because garbage-in), you just get `0` and never knew about the garbage-in. Instead, perform a normal cast: `var x = ((double?)reader[1]).GetValueOrDefault()`. If it's castable, it will work and give you the value or `0`. If not, it will throw an exception and you can fix the index value.

Comment: Also, you can use the `GetValueOrDefault(defaultValue)` overload if you have a default value other than `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already know the column position (ordinal) as it seems in your case, you are much better off using the correct data type retriever and check for null before hand like this

```
double x = reader.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : reader.GetDouble(1);
```

Comment: I like this solution, it really makes it clear what you're attempting to achieve.

Comment: @Jason How could this answer be modified to qualify based on column name? I.e., if I changed my examples above to use reader["Some Column"] instead of [1].

Comment: @tjm6f4 unfortunately there is no `Get<Type>` that takes a column name.  The best option is to first get the ordinal, like `int col1 = reader.GetOrdinal("Some Column");` then you can do `double x = reader.IsDBNull(col1 ) ? 0 : reader.GetDouble(col1 );`, otherwise you're stuck with the cast then check technique

Comment: @Jason do you see any problems with this as a solution:

`Double x = (reader[“Col”] is DBNull) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(reader[“Col”]);`

Comment: @tjm6f4 that should do the job nicely, but if you're doing this in a loop, you'll get better perf if you first get the ordinal then loop using the col number with the respective `Get` method

Comment: @Jason Does the "is" keyword and/or Convert method and/or multiple lookups on the string column name cause a performance hit?  I.e., which of these?

Comment: @tjm6f4 your biggest hit will be the lookup on the column, see the remarks in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f01t4cfy.aspx, while storing the column ordinal and re-using that will reduce the lookups

Answer (score 2):

Your two examples are functionally equivalent: `null` will resolve to `0`, `double` will resolve to its value. For most practical purposes, they both run in no time. (if you actually need to know, the latter should run slightly faster) I prefer the latter (using null-coalescing) for readability.

However, note that if you might encounter other values, such as an `int` or `string`, you might want to consider using [`Convert.ToDouble`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx3x7f55.aspx), which will attempt to convert whatever value you give it. It will also default a `null` as `0`.

Answer (score 1):

the `as` keyword has an extra cost, because it is already casting the object into the wanted type.

Use `var x = !reader.IsDBNull(1) ? r.GetDouble(1) : 0;`